# Angular 2 best practices

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to evaluate angular 2 for possible future use. I have limited angular/angular 2 experience. I have read deployment documents on available and have configured spring dispatcher servlet to follow rewrite rules recommended by angular

So far I have managed integrate spring controllers and angular code so that one servlet serves both services and angular files and in general works fine as everything (including angular2 code editing) can be done in eclipse.

I am trying to figure out best develop, build and deployment strategy for angular 2 applications.

Many of my questions are essentially boiling down to having multiple views of the same application and not serving/not being aware of modules which are not needed. Simplest example might be serving light component on mobile devices and heavy component on desktop.

1. How do you control access to index.html. My login page is separate and main application and all related services needs to be authenticated. My current approach is to use base path "/app" and index.html is served on "/app" by the servlet/spring. Spring security controls the access to "/app"
2. How do I control page configurations? For example, based on settings, I need to hide certain components. I can hide the components today, but page is aware of the component. We have customers who subscribe to certain features and page contents are based on features setting. If you are not subsribed to feature, I would try to avoid all references of the components not allowed.
3. Can I have multiple "index.html" files equivalent which builds lists of required components/modules for given customer. Server can serve right "index.html" back to browser. For example, at build time, can I say build customer1.html and customer2.html with needed components and server can serve either of these files as server is aware who the customer is.
4. Exposing only one page in the application - some of our customers use only one particular functionality in the application. For them this is the complete application as they manage rest of the features via API. This problem is similar to #2, but still different as it's only one page application.
5. What is recomended way to split components vs modules etc. If I have typical web application say "/account", "/shopping", should I build modules for "/account" and "/shopping" or just try to create components for each end point. These end points will share some components, but does have disticint functionality
6. Deployment configurations -  I understand some of these can be controlled using environment files. It seems like environment files are committed to git. How do I externalize some of these configurations so that code change and build processed is not needed. For example, if I have assets url and want to change it, I just want to change the configuration file. My current approach is to have a configuration service which reads java properties from external location and serves data needed by angular.

Comment: Most of what you're talking about (1-5) can be achieved using [`canLoad`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanLoad-interface.html) guard on lazy loaded feature modules, with some thoughtful planing. [Read through the guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) for more info. Make sure your modules can work in isolation. What to group/share in a module will be clearer as you build features. Deployment is more about tooling then app itself; with CLI you can make optimized production build and deploy in few minutes. Hope some of this helps (;

Comment: perhaps ask these questions separately, on a different forum